# how to store rejected jobs array in database?

Tags: laravel

I have jobs and registered users. I want to save record of users ids who rejected jobs in comma seperated array like 1,2,5,7 and save that array in rejected_by column in database so that i have record of users who rejected job offers.when any user rejects job array should save in database.

```
 $userID = $request->input('user_id');
 $jobID = $request->input('job_id');

if ($jobAction == "reject") {

    $saveArray = explode(",", $userID);
    $check = count($saveArray );
    for ($i = 0; $i < $check; $i++) {

    DB::table('jobs')->insert(array('rejected_by' => $saveArray [$i]));
      }

    $updateJobStatus = Job::where('id', $jobID)->update(['rejected_by' => $saveArray ]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)  or use JSON via [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) after use them you can save it to your db field

```
 $userID = $request->input('user_id');
 $jobID = $request->input('job_id');

if ($jobAction == "reject") {

    $saveArray = explode(",", $userID);
    $check = count($saveArray );
    for ($i = 0; $i < $check; $i++) {

    DB::table('jobs')->insert(array('rejected_by' => $saveArray [$i]));
      }

    $updateJobStatus = Job::where('id', $jobID)->update(['rejected_by' => json_encode($saveArray)]);
   }
```

and change `rejected_by` data type to `json` in `mysql`

Comment: @DaniyalMughal you can convert php array to json and save json to db

Comment: @DaniyalMughal you can not save php array in db. `Job::where('id', $jobID)->update(['rejected_by' => $saveArray ]);`  $saveArray is a php array

Comment: Can you edit my code so i can clearly understand your concept?

Comment: It is not storing multiple ids.. overwriting on storing value.. i want to store multiple users ids who rejects job.

Comment: @DaniyalMughal it is save multiple ids . You should use `json_decode()` when you want to use data